# Using thirdparty not serializable object in Spark streaming transformations

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm developing a java application in spark streaming (it seems that scala is better for spark, but unfortunately I have limited time and it will cost me too much time to learn it and start using it) and I need to use a thirdparty class in a transformation function which is not serializable. All the solutions for coping with this is to make a singleton static object for every executor JVM and all the examples are in scala using a static wrapper method which implements the singleton pattern. In my app I'm using spring DI, so I initialize a singleton object and then instead of using it as a class field I make it static, which is basically the same as the scala solution. The problem is that a strange exception occurs:

```
Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1951)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1226)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1168)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1168)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1168)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1071)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1037)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1037)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1037)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:963)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:963)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:963)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:962)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(RDD.scala:1488)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1467)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1467)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1467)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$saveAsTextFiles$1$$anonfun$11.apply(DStream.scala:925)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$saveAsTextFiles$1$$anonfun$11.apply(DStream.scala:923)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:254)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:254)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:254)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:253)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: unexpected exception type
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.throwMiscException(ObjectStreamClass.java:1582)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1154)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1817)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1909)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1909)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1909)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1909)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1909)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda.readResolve(SerializedLambda.java:230)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1148)
... 117 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid lambda deserialization
```

So can someone tell me what is the right way to use a unserializable object(without initializing it on every execution) on the executor nodes?

Here is the class where I use the problematic dependency(DatabaseReader). It is executed on the executor nodes:

```
import com.maxmind.geoip2.DatabaseReader;
import com.maxmind.geoip2.model.CityResponse;
import com.qello.models.Event;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

import java.net.InetAddress;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class GeoEnricher extends AbstractEnricher {

    @NonNull
    private static DatabaseReader geoIpDatabaseReader;

    public GeoEnricher(Enricher nextEnricher, DatabaseReader geoIpDatabaseReader) {
        super(nextEnricher);
        this.geoIpDatabaseReader = geoIpDatabaseReader;
    }

    @Override
    public void doEnrich(Event event) {
        try {
            CityResponse cityResponse = geoIpDatabaseReader.city(InetAddress.getByName(event.getIp()));
            if (cityResponse != null) {
                event.setContinent(cityResponse.getContinent().getName());
                event.setCountry(cityResponse.getCountry().getName());
                event.setLatitude(cityResponse.getLocation().getLatitude());           
                event.setLongitude(cityResponse.getLocation().getLongitude());
                event.setIpTimezone(cityResponse.getLocation().getTimeZone());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I get the Enricher instance in the main method:

```
Enricher enricher = applicationContext.getBean(Enricher.class);
```

And here is the transformation where it's used(Events are consumed from a kinesis stream and then the transformations are made):

```
kinesisStream
    .flatMap(bytes -> {
        return objectMapper.readValue(bytes, BatchEvent.class);
    })
    .mapToPair(batchEvent -> new Tuple2<>(batchEvent.getEvents().get(0).getDeviceId(), batchEvent.getEvents()))
    .map(deviceIdEvents -> {
        for(Event event : deviceIdEvents._2) {
            enricher.enrich(event);
        }

        return deviceIdEvents;
    })
```

Comment: Regarding Scala for Spark, if you have 23 minutes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBoSgiLV_NQ

Comment: Spring DI won't help you because the executors don't have Spring DI initialization to have your singleton instantiated. Do you have the code? There might be other ways.

Comment: @maasg Spring DI is not invoked on the executors. I edited the post with the class which is causing the problem.

Comment: It could be that class internally has some lambda that does not implement `Serializable`. If you declare `DatabaseReader` as `transient` will that change anything?

Comment: Could you show how are you using/calling it at the moment?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov transient as I expected didn't change anything.

Comment: @maasg I edited the post with some more code added.

Comment: @HristoAngelov, but that should mean the problem is not the `DatabaseReader` class, right? Java servialization is supposed to ignore transient fields, assuming standard serialization is used.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov maybe there's a little misunderstanding because the field is static, so it's not serialized. When I removed the static this means that it must be serialized and that leads to the infamous TaskNotSerializable exception. That is the problem which I want to solve- how to use the DatabaseReader in the executors. The above code is partly wrong, because as it's a static field that means that the executors will take the current value from the class which will be null. I changed the initialization with a static block but unfortunately nothing changed- the same exception occurs.

Comment: @HristoAngelov, I didn't notice `static` modifier - my bad. That then also means that it has nothing to actually do with your class being serializable or not. Judging by the text of your exception, there is a problem with deserializing a lambda function contained somewhere, presumably inside that `Event` class.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Ok, but that is what I want to know- how to achieve the usage of a non serializable class in an executor. When I remove the static modifier then TaskNotSerializable is thrown(which is normal), when I made a static initialization of the field then the exception in my post is thrown and I can't understand where exactly the problem is from it.

Comment: @HristoAngelov, at this point, my bet is your actual exception has nothing to do with that dependency - but if you add it as field to Job, then it happens before your actual problem manifests itself. And the actual problem you're having is somewhere else entirely. According to sources of the `DAGScheduler`, your system produces **lambda deserialization exception** when attempting to execute the job. I'm assuming the only things that get deserialized here are the events (or am I wrong)?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov You are write, I removed the dependency it's still throwing the same error. I'm investigating it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the worst-case scenario, you can use a non-serializable service by instantiating it on each executor every time that the data is processed. We can achieve that using `mapPartition` like this:

```
kinessStream
.flatMap(...)
.mapToPair(...)
.mapPartitions(iterator -> {
    Enricher enricher = new EnricherService(...); // instantiate my service locally 
                                                  // should be able to create an instance *without* requiring DI
    for(Event event : deviceIdEvents._2) {
        enricher.enrich(event);  // this is strongly discouraged. Avoid mutable state!
    }
    return deviceIdEvents;
    // this should be a better option:
    // return iterator.map(event -> enricher.enrich(event));
 } 
})
```

A better alternative would be to use a lazy singleton object that gets initialized on each executor when accessed.

Pseudo-code:

```
...stream setup...
.mapPartitions(iterator -> {
    Enricher enricher = EnricherSingleton.getInstance(); // get a local instance
    ...same as above...    
})
```

The advantage of the singleton alternative is that it's able to reduce the overhead of creating a new instance each time, provided that the service instance is thread-safe or sufficient care is taken to provide a thread-safe alternative (e.g. `ThreadLocal` variables).
In any case, the `mapPartitions` operation amortizes the cost of the service creation among potentially large amounts of data points contained in each partition and execution is still parallelized.

In the event that none of these options are possible (thinking about the DI framework only able to inject dependencies on the driver), we can use the service locally, at the expense of losing all parallelism in our process.

```
transient Enricher enricher = applicationContext.getBean(Enricher.class);
...stream setup...
.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
     Event[] events = rdd.collect(); // All data is sent to the driver. This is a bottleneck
     Events[] enrichedEvents = events.map(event -> 
         enricher.enrich(event));  // suggesting to use a map function instead of mutating in-place. The mutation used in the question would work as well. 
     // do something with enrichedEvents 

 }
```

Comment: The first option is not acceptable- object initialization takes too much time. The second option is pretty much the same with what I did(the static initialization) and it continues to throw the same exception. The third option is also not acceptable- we are talking for big amount of data and we can not lose the parallelism. The bad thing here is that the exception is not that descriptive and I can't understand where is the actual problem.

Comment: @HristoAngelov can I see the static initialization code that you used? It *must* be lazy. Initialization cannot take place on the driver. If you are using DI, it's probably wrong.

Comment: @HristoAngelov Seeing your code(*), the class that needs to become a singleton is `GeoEnricher`, then apply option (2) to use it.  (* should not post as an answer but rather as an edit of your question, btw)

Comment: maybe you are right- it's more logical, but it turned out that the problem is in one of the transformations- jackson's ObjectMapper can't be deserialized for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I do a lazy initialization. Here's the code:

```
private static DatabaseReader databaseReader = null;

public static DatabaseReader getInstance() {
    try {
        if(databaseReader == null) {
            databaseReader = new DatabaseReader.Builder(new File(SparkFiles.get("GeoLite2-City.mmdb")))
                    .withCache(new CHMCache())
                    .fileMode(Reader.FileMode.MEMORY)
                    .build();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return databaseReader;
}
```